# Usercontrol render with object asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, ascx

I am working on one project in which I need to send an email. The mail format has been made in an `ascx` Usercontrol and that control will be used to render the email body, where certain variables such as name and date are filled from another method.

My main problem is that I want to render the control in the email body along with the object of a class and method. Actually I want to do it in the fashion of MVC (i.e. passing the model in front end.) Is there any good way to do this?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
string path = "Email Template/LeaveRequestedEmailToAPPREC.ascx";
body = RenderUserControl(path,lrd);
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
try
{
    msg.From = new MailAddress(fromemail, fromname);
    msg.To.Add(toemail);
    msg.Subject = subject;
    msg.Body = body;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
    sc.Host = "smtp.ntc.net.np";
    sc.Port = 25;
    sc.Send(msg);
    msg.Dispose();
    msg = null;
    return true;
}



//========  Rendering the UserControl ==========
public string RenderUserControl(string path,object viewmodel)
{            
    Page holder = new Page();
    UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)holder.LoadControl(path);

    HtmlForm tempForm = new HtmlForm();  //if the UserControl contain some server controls like TextBox, Button, Add a form wrapped them.
    tempForm.Controls.Add(viewControl);
    holder.Controls.Add(tempForm);

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(holder, output, false);
    string outputToReturn = output.ToString();
    output.Close();
    return outputToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm grasping exactly what you want entirely, but you might try using the [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htwek607.aspx) method exposed by all controls, as such, for example:

```
using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
{
    var builder = new System.IO.StreamWriter(buffer);
    using (var stream = new HtmlTextWriter(builder))
    {
        holder.RenderControl(stream);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```